# Android Webview - Change Input Text

Tags: java, android, input, webview

I've set up my webview properly and I execute my Javascript in the onPageFinished method.

The problem is that whenever I try to change the value of my input, no matter what I do, I end up with the entire webview being replaced by the value of the input that I'm trying to replace.

```
view.loadUrl("javascript:document.forms[0].elements['password'].value = 'test';");
```

Any ideas?

PS. This code in the same place works perfectly.

```
view.loadUrl("javascript:checkForm()");
```

This executes the checks and submits the form. I get a popup "Please enter a value" after running this.

I have also tried `document.getElementsByName("password")[0].value = 'test';` Same result.

RESOLVED: It was the emulator causing the problem. I tested directly on my phone with USB debugging switched on and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Your first line of code works for me using id or name attributes:

```
view.loadUrl("javascript:document.forms[0].elements['password'].value = 'test';");
```

the second line, works with getElementById but doesn't with getElementByName:

```
view.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementByName('password').value = 'test';");
```

So, that's not the problem. Maybe if you post the rest of the code.

Comment: Sorry, it's probably document.getElementsByName('password')[0].value

Comment: Maybe it's my emulator. I'll test it on my phone with USB.

Comment: Yeah. It works on my phone, so it was the emulator causing the trouble. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You try to change the view, so you need to use:

> .dispatchEvent(new Event('input')) ",null).

Try this:

```
view.evaluateJavascript("javascript:  " +
    "var password= document.getElementById('password'); " +
    "password.value = 'test'; " +
    "password.dispatchEvent(new Event('input')) ",null);
```